# how to fit a button to a circular image in scene builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, button, javafx

Is there a way to implement a button with a circular shape and has a circular image? I am using the Scene builder and javafx plugin in Eclipse.
I am trying to implement a Play button. I can add easily an image to the button , the problem is that the image is a round and the button is a rectangular shape. how can i fit both ?
and thanks

Here is the image !

http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/grunge-brushed-metal-pewter-icons-media/001103-grunge-brushed-metal-pewter-icon-media-a-media32-forward.png

Comment: See also: [How to make a javafx button with circle shape of 3xp diameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850828/how-to-make-a-javafx-button-with-circle-shape-of-3xp-diameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Scene Builder without any custom CSS file, just add this rule on the Inspector/Properties->Style textfield:

```
-fx-background-radius: 100;
```

and you'll have your round button (You'll have to fix the sizes of the image and the button properly):

[image: Round button]

Or you could use a custom CSS file:

```
.button {
    -fx-background-radius: 100;
}
```

and load it on your FXML file with the `StyleSheets` button.

Note you'll probably need also to add some styling for `focused`, `hover`, `armed` or `disabled` pseudoclasses.

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine with that image.However with another , the image button looks awful ! here is the image : https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1246x701q90/537/srU4IZ.png

Comment: You need to fix the sizes: make the button smaller so you don't see the borders. Besides, the image is not transparent.

Comment: Thanks Jose, I fixed the transparent issue by changing it to a .png  format instead of .jpg . However the image-button borders wasn't solved even when i made it smaller . Image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1246x701q90/661/bXBLra.png

Comment: Set the min/pref/max sizes of the button (Inspector->Layout) as you need to make it smaller.

Comment: Ok, then consider accepting the answer as valid, so it may be useful for others too.