# How to set border color to Avatar in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, avatar, gluon

How can i set border color to an Avatar object in javafx? How many ways exists to do it?

It's not just css mode, also by code. The object i want to set border color is this:

http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/3.0.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Avatar.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see two related approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38004410/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @trashgod this is not a duplicated question, `avatar` is a custom control from the Gluon Mobile library, and built-in JavaFX css doesn't apply.

Comment: @JoséPereda: thanks; reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom control `Avatar` from the Gluon Mobile [library](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Avatar.html) has API for setting the image and the radius.

Currently it doesn't provide API for setting the border color, but it can be done, based on how the control is designed.

If you check it with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), the control has an `ImageView` and a `Circle` on top, with styleClass `decoration`.

So by code you can set the color of this circle:

```
avatar.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(1).setStyle("-fx-stroke: red");
```

or better:

```
avatar.lookup(".decoration").setStyle("-fx-stroke: red");
```

With CSS is easier:

```
.avatar > .decoration {
    -fx-stroke: red;
}
```