# How to press on circular icon to get drop down menu on javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

How should one get a drop down menu when pressed on an icon, in my case, it needs to be a small circular icon. 
Choice box gives me a rectangular box. However, I need a concise icon which will show a drop down when clicked.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with Swing, so don't add the tag.

Comment: Maybe `show()` a `ContextMenu` when clicking a `Button` with a `graphic` but no `text`? If you encounter a specific problem, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down menu of a `ChoiceBox` is a `ContextMenu` so you can just use that class yourself to generate your drop down menu. You make a circular button with the image on it ([like this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850828/how-to-make-a-javafx-button-with-circle-shape-of-3xp-diameter)) and then when it is clicked, you show a `ContextMenu` with the `MenuItems` that you want. Use the `show(Node anchor, Side side, double dx, double dy)` function of `ContextMenu` to show it on the bottom of the button.